# Render a different div when input is filled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this empty input [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjsM3.png) and I want to replace the icon and the text there with the image preview when an image is inserted in it. [The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdxkT.png). I want to remove the "Drop app logo......." when the image preview is there. It does'nt look neat the way it is right now

```js
const images = files.map((file) => (
    <img
      key={file.name}
      src={file.preview}
      alt="image"
      style={{ width: "50%", height: "50%" }}
    />
  ));


    <Flex width={{ sm: "340px", md: "450px" }}>
       {images && (<><div>{images}</div></>)}
       
         {images !== null && (<><Box>
          <AiOutlineCloudUpload size={30} />
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <Text fontSize="sm"> Drop app logo here or{" "}
               <Button variant="link" color="#002c8a">browse
               </Button>
            </Text>
           </Box>
           </>
           )}
    </Flex>
```

Comment: What's the `images` initial value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boolean logic is incorrect; `images` is an array, and in JavaScript, arrays (even empty arrays) are never [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). So the `images && (<><div>{images}</div></>)` section will always render, because `images` is always truthy, but the `images !== null && (<><Box>...` block will always render too, because `images` is never null.

Try something like this instead, to render images if images exist and to render the upload prompt if no images exist. (I'm also removing a spurious React fragment (`<>`).)

```
<Flex width={{ sm: "340px", md: "450px" }}>
  {images.length > 0 && <div>{images}</div>}
       
  {images.length === 0 && (<>
    <Box>
      <AiOutlineCloudUpload size={30} />
    </Box>
    <Box>
      <Text fontSize="sm"> Drop app logo here or{" "}
        <Button variant="link" color="#002c8a">browse
        /Button>
      </Text>
    </Box>
  </>)}
</Flex>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the text when image is loaded

maybe you can add conditional inside `<Text></Text>` tag

it will append empty string when image !== null

```js
const images = files.map((file) => (
    <img
      key={file.name}
      src={file.preview}
      alt="image"
      style={{ width: "50%", height: "50%" }}
    />
  ));


    <Flex width={{ sm: "340px", md: "450px" }}>
       {images && (<><div>{images}</div></>)}
       
         {images !== null && (<><Box>
          <AiOutlineCloudUpload size={30} />
          </Box>
          <Box>
            <Text fontSize="sm"> {images !== null ? "" : "Drop app logo here or "}
               <Button variant="link" color="#002c8a">browse
               </Button>
            </Text>
           </Box>
           </>
           )}
    </Flex>
```